# Problem when resampling OHLC data from 1 min to 15min interval

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stock

I have a data set containing Open, High, Low, Close prices for every 1 minute,for a one year interval,  like below:

```
                           Open     High        Low          Close
Date_time               
2020-01-01 17:00:00     1.12120     1.12121     1.12117     1.12120
2020-01-01 17:01:00     1.12106     1.12135     1.12106     1.12135
2020-01-01 17:02:00     1.12136     1.12139     1.12136     1.12139
2020-01-01 17:03:00     1.12135     1.12135     1.12120     1.12122
2020-01-01 17:04:00     1.12122     1.12125     1.12122     1.12125
```

There is no NaN or Null in this data set and I checked it with:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

output:

```
Open     0
High     0
Low      0
Close    0
dtype: int64
```

I want to resample these to 15min intervals, by using:

```
dff = df.resample('15min').agg({
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': 'last'})
```

the output will be:

```
                           Open     High        Low        Close
Date_time               
2020-01-01 17:00:00     1.12120     1.12139     1.12106     1.12127
2020-01-01 17:15:00     1.12127     1.12154     1.12127     1.12146
2020-01-01 17:30:00     1.12147     1.12156     1.12138     1.12154
2020-01-01 17:45:00     1.12155     1.12166     1.12143     1.12143
2020-01-01 18:00:00     1.12143     1.12218     1.12142     1.12202
```

which sounds OK but when I run :

```
dff.isnull().sum()
```

the output is:

```
Open     10121
High     10121
Low      10121
Close    10121
dtype: int64
```

which means that almost half of the dataset is Null.
I searched a lot but did't find anything useful. Is there another way for resampling the dataset into 15min intervals? and where is the problem that causes Null values in dataset?

**More info**: size of `dff` is :

```
dff.count()
output:
Open     24919
High     24919
Low      24919
Close    24919
dtype: int64
```

**Update**:
I just used

```
dff = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).agg({"Open": "first", 
                                             "Low": "min", 
                                             "High": "max",
                                             "Close": "last"})
```

but still half of the dataset is Null.
I attached dataset `csv` file [here](https://ufile.io/p1dy2if0)

**update#2** : thanks to @not_speshal, I found out that the size of `df` is `(372335,4)` but the size of `df.resample("1min").last()` is
`(372275,4)` which I think means that I don't have data for some of the 1min intervals, How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably don't have any data for some of the 15min intervals. Check the size of `df.resample("1min").last()` with the size of `df`.

Comment: @not_speshal it was OK, both had the same value for their size

Comment: @not_speshal sorry, you were right, size of ```df``` is (372335,4) but size of resampled to 1 min is (372275,4) , how can I solve this ?

Comment: You don't have any data on the weekends (Fri 5 pm to Sunday 5 pm). Resample is filling NaN for these days.

Comment: @not_speshal, Thanks a lot, yeah I used ```ohlc_dict = {'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close': 'last'} 
df.resample('15Min').apply(ohlc_dict).dropna(how='any')``` and it seems that we have no more issues here. I appreciate your advises.  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your csv file doesn't have data for many days (probably when the markets are closed?). You can instead `resample` and then only keep rows that exist in the original data like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv("EURUSD_2020.csv")
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]+" "+df["time"])
df = df.drop(["Date", "time"], axis=1).set_index("datetime").astype("float")

dff = df.resample("15min").agg({'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close': 'last'})
dff = dff[dff.index.isin(df.index)]
```